# why sqlachemy Table or class different？

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a question for sqlalchemy;

Why the sqlalchemy orm Can't obj.select?

code on there.
this orm：

```py
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Boolean, Column, Date, Float, Index, Integer, JSON, MetaData, String, Table, Text, text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

metadata = MetaData()


t_clinicaltrials = Table(
    'clinicaltrials', metadata,
    Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('shuimubio_auto_id.clinicaltrials_auto_id'::regclass)"), comment='数据库自增主键'),
    Column('nct_id', String, comment='Clinicaltrial的唯一ID'),
    Column('study_title', String, comment='标题'),
    Column('study_type', String, server_default=text("0"), comment="研究类型(现有四种'Expanded Access', 'Interventional', None, 'Observational')"),
    Column('phase_id_list', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='研究阶段(逻辑外键表phase)'),
    Column('intervention_id_list', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='介入方式(逻辑外键表 intervention_function 给药方式)'),
    Column('intervention_model', String, comment='干预模型'),
    Column('primary_purpose', String, comment='首要目标(主要的目的)'),
    Column('masking', String, comment='设盲方法'),
    Column('conditions_id_list', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='适应症列表(逻辑外键表 condition)'),
    Column('number_enrolled', Integer, comment='入组人数'),
    Column('sex', String(16), comment='性别(逻辑外键表 sex)'),
    Column('study_age', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='受试者年龄'),
    Column('study_start_date', Date, comment='试验开始时间'),
    Column('study_completion_date', Date, comment='试验结束时间'),
    Column('official_title', String, comment='官方标题'),
    Column('sponsor', String, comment='资助机构'),
    Column('collaborators', JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='合作者'),
    Column('result_first_posted', Date, comment='首次发布时间')
)
```

this metadata：

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class Clinicaltrial(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'clinicaltrials'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('shuimubio_auto_id.clinicaltrials_auto_id'::regclass)"), comment='数据库自增主键')
    nct_id = Column(String, comment='Clinicaltrial的唯一ID')
    study_title = Column(String, comment='标题')
    study_type = Column(String, server_default=text("0"), comment="研究类型(现有四种'Expanded Access', 'Interventional', None, 'Observational')")
    phase_id_list = Column(JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='研究阶段(逻辑外键表phase)')
    intervention_id_list = Column(JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='介入方式(逻辑外键表 intervention_function 给药方式)')
    intervention_model = Column(String, comment='干预模型')
    primary_purpose = Column(String, comment='首要目标(主要的目的)')
    masking = Column(String, comment='设盲方法')
    conditions_id_list = Column(JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='适应症列表(逻辑外键表 condition)')
    number_enrolled = Column(Integer, comment='入组人数')
    sex = Column(String(16), comment='性别(逻辑外键表 sex)')
    study_age = Column(JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='受试者年龄')
    study_start_date = Column(Date, comment='试验开始时间')
    study_completion_date = Column(Date, comment='试验结束时间')
    official_title = Column(String, comment='官方标题')
    sponsor = Column(String, comment='资助机构')
    collaborators = Column(JSONB(astext_type=Text()), comment='合作者')
    result_first_posted = Column(Date, comment='首次发布时间')
```

this code has error
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'filter_by'

```py
Query(Clinicaltrial).filter_by(Uniprot.uniprot_id.in_(uniprot_Ids))
```

But this line of code will work。

```py
select__filter = t_uniprot.select().filter(t_uniprot.columns["uniprot_id"].in_(uniprot_Ids))
return await database.fetch_all(select__filter)
```

What's the difference between the two and how to change this class orm Make it accessible for select attr

Answer (score 1):

According to the [migration guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#orm-query-unified-with-core-select):

> The `Query` object (as well as the `BakedQuery` and `ShardedQuery` extensions) become long term legacy objects, replaced by the direct usage of the `select()` construct in conjunction with the `Session.execute()` method.

So we can use `select(…).where(…)` for both ORM and Core (Table) queries:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData, Column, String,\
    BigInteger, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

Base = declarative_base()


class Clinicaltrial(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'clinicaltrials'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    nct_id = Column(String, comment='Clinicaltrial的唯一ID')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Clinicaltrial(id={self.id})>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO clinicaltrials (id, nct_id) "
        "VALUES (1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'), (3, 'test3')"
    )

with Session(engine) as sess:
    # ORM query
    q = select(Clinicaltrial).where(Clinicaltrial.id.in_([1, 3]))
    results = sess.execute(q).all()
    print(results)
    # [(<Clinicaltrial(id=1)>,), (<Clinicaltrial(id=3)>,)]

    # Core query
    ct = Table("clinicaltrials", MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
    q = select(ct).where(ct.c.id.in_([1, 3]))
    results = sess.execute(q).all()
    print(results)
    # [(1, 'test1'), (3, 'test3')]
```